# Running android sdkmanager results in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk-manager

I just installed `Android Studio` on `macOS`.  I need to accept the license. How do I run  `sdkmanager` ?

```
$tools/bin/sdkmanager 
APP_HOME=/Users/steve/Library/Android/sdk/tools
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
    at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
    at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

Note that I am running `java11` in which `javax.xml.bind` is not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interim workaround is that I reset the `jdk` version to java8. Then the `sdkmanager` was able to run.  It remains to be seen if there were no other issues.

Comment: how did u reset the jdk??

Comment: You have to download the jdk8 and set the path properly . `brew install jenv openjdk@8`

Answer (score 10):

- install java 8,
- open the android studio > go to configure > select sdk manager > go to sdk tools > make a tick on android sdk command line tools >apply > and wait for installation
- enter the command

> flutter doctor --android-licenses

- and accept all the licenses by typing y

Comment: This appears to be alternate command that does also work.

Comment: Android SDK Command-line Tools was the key for me. Thanks for mentioning it. There are a couple of other tools with somewhat similar names which force me to look twice.